# Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria Only when publishing the API

Tags: c#, api, certificate

I'm trying to use webservice which in turn needs a certeficate

the certeficate is installed on local computer and my user account its' installed in my store(personal).

In development mode( visual studio ) i used the following code to link the cert:

```
string thumbprintVal = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Thumbprint"];
                mPortType.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                 StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                thumbprintVal);
```

it's working fine in the development.

but when i publish the code to IIS it fails by giving this error:

> Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria:
>   StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'CurrentUser', FindType
>   'FindByThumbprint', FindValue 'Thumbprint value'."}

could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StoreLocation.CurrentUser` may point to different store location for user that runs your IIS application. When you are running application in development mode, it runs as `you` so it has access to your certification store location.